# Typescript loses typing in destructuring assignment

Tags: typescript, types, destructuring

When using destructuring assignment and variable as property name Typescript seems like loses types.

```js
interface O {
    [val: string]: string;
}

const o: O = {
    foo: ''
};

const f = (name: string) => {
    const {[name]: value} = o;
    // now `value` has type any, how to make it type `string`?

    const value1 = o[name] || '';
    // and `value1` has correct type `string`
};
```

Comment: That actually looks like a bug in TypeScript, I suggest you search in their issues, and if none is found, open one.

Comment: It is [a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16260).

Comment: I have some of those issues with angular 2. If you try to assign from object notation the type became messy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's typescript a bug, there are some issues on this code

```
const {[name]: value} = o ;
```

what is this line, you are defining a const with no name, then using something like type and assigning o

Also what is `value`?

Since I don't know what was your idea I can suggest these codes:

If you want to consider it as type

```
const x : {[name:string]:string} = o;
```

If you want to use it as value

```
const x = {[name] : 'my value'};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

After thinking it some more, its obvious that both cases should return the same result, and typescript probably doesn't considered the possible prototype of the object. so it should return string type.

And you must protect the two cases of missing entries and possible non string prototype access.

**Original:**

The value given to the destructuring is a `string`, and can be **any string**, including things like *`__proto__`* or *`constructor`* that will result in a non `string` type.

If you know the optional keys that you might have, then this will work:

```
const f = (name: keyof typeof o) => {
    const {[name]: value} = o;
    // now `value` has type string
};
```

I think the bug is in the latter example without destructuring. By passing certain strings you might get a non `string` value.